# can I get the Image data from FirebaseUI Storage from native app code and send it to Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

**I am not asking about how to use Firebase Storage**

currently my app using native iOS and native Android, and I want to recreate it using Flutter. but before I learn about Flutter, I want to ensure something first.

to download image from Cloud Storage, my native app using [Glide FirebaseUI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui) for Android, and also [SDWebImage FirebaseUI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui) for iOS

for Android it will be like this

```
// Reference to an image file in Cloud Storage
val storageReference = Firebase.storage.reference

// ImageView in your Activity
val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)

// Download directly from StorageReference using Glide
Glide.with(this /* context */)
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView) // downloaded data will be put into an image view
```

as you can see, that Glide code will download the data, and it will be put into an image view, but as far as I know, Flutter will build UI as code right? there is no such thing like 'view'

so my question is, is there any trick to get image data from FirebaseUI taken in Glide and SDWebImage FirebaseUI storage to be sent to flutter app?

or can I still use that code in Flutter? I am worried it can't be used because the code will involve 'view' and there is no 'view' in Flutter right

because, if using FirebaseUI storage, I don't need to save the download data URL in the Firestore document

Answer (score 0):

If you move to Flutter I would recommend to use Flutter solutons for such simple stuff. The [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package is great to display images and cache them for Android and iOS. There is no need for a View to display an Image in Flutter.

If you need the downloadURL from a ref you can use the [getDownladURL](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference/getDownloadURL.html) method on a reference to get it.

Comment: yup, I know it already about Network Image, but it needs imageURL right, if using FirebaseUI storage then I will not need the URL, I just need Storage Reference. because I need to write a lot of images URL in my Firestore document, and the URL created using Firebase admin SDK is ridiculously long. and there is a chance to fail when creating download URL on my admin SDK. so there is better if I use FirebaseUI for storage.

Comment: but thanks anyway, it seems it is not available, at least at the moment, so I need to change my approach

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer. You can get the downloadURL using `getDownloadURL` from the reference.